# Java code parsing error - but all brackets closed

Tags: java, parsing

ignore the content but below is my code and I am continously getting the parsing error but it appears to me that I have all my brackets closed properly, I have looked at it again and again, maybe I am just going full ham here, any help would be appreciated.

```
class java_ca

{

public static void main(String[] args);

        char ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, ans5, ans6, ans7, ans8, ans9, ans10, ans11, ans12;
        int totaly, totaln;



                {while ((ans1 != 'y') && (ans1 != 'n'))

                    {
                        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
                        ans1=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans1=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans1=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

                    }
                    {
                        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
                        ans2=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans2=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans2=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

                    }
                    {
                        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
                        ans3=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans3=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans3=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

                    }
                    {
                        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
                        ans4=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans4=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans4=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

                    }
                    {
                        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
                        ans5=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans5=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans5=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

                    }
                    {
                        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
                        ans6=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans6=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans6=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

                    }
                    {
                        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
                        ans7=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans7=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans7=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

                    }
                    {
                        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
                        ans8=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans8=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans8=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

                    }
                    {
                        System.out.println("1) Do You like to read?");
                        ans9=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans9=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans9=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

                    }
                    {
                        System.out.println("10. Did you like this surevy?");
                        ans10=Keyboard.readChar();
                            if(ans10=='y'){totaly++;}
                            else if(ans1=='n'){totaln++;}
                            else{System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");
                    }
            }
}
```

Comment: **What does the error say**? Did you read it?

Comment: All of the braces in your method are wrong or useless.

Comment: "{while ((ans1 != 'y') && (ans1 != 'n'))". Really ???

Comment: It helps to format the code correctly. Here to help us see issue, when you write it to help you spot errors

Answer (score 3):

Your method braces are off.

First thing I see, you have error here:

```
public static void main(String[] args);
```

It should be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    --------------
    --------------

}
```

Comment: your correct the ; wasnt supposed to be there but I have fixed that and continue to get the same error

Comment: Your braces look wrong at several places.

Answer (score 1):

You have a massive overdose of `{}` in mostly the wrong places, your code looks like a the result of a copy-paste job gone wrong, and fixed in the wrong places afterwards (ie, by adding stuff instead of removing stuff).

There's what it should more or less look like.  Please not that 1) I still have my doubts about the program logic itself and 2) as I suspect this is homework, there's still plenty of work to correct other logical mistakes, I tried to focus solely on the `{}` issue.  And as @Mark already said: ***format your code properly*** or use an editor that formats the code for you, it ***will*** help you to spot this kind of issues quickly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, ans5, ans6, ans7, ans8, ans9, ans10, ans11, ans12;
    int totaly, totaln;


    while ((ans1 != 'y') && (ans1 != 'n')) {
        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
        ans1 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans1 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans1 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

        }

        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
        ans2 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans2 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans2 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

        }
        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
        ans3 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans3 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans3 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

        }
        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
        ans4 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans4 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans4 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

        }
        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
        ans5 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans5 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans5 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

        }
        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
        ans6 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans6 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans6 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

        }
        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
        ans7 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans7 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans7 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

        }
        System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");
        ans8 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans8 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans8 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

        }
        System.out.println("1) Do You like to read?");
        ans9 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans9 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans9 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");

        }
        System.out.println("10. Did you like this surevy?");
        ans10 = Keyboard.readChar();
        if (ans10 == 'y') {
            totaly++;
        } else if (ans1 == 'n') {
            totaln++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection, please enter y or n to answer the questions");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of your lines starting with `else` (but not `else if`) has a `{` with no matching `}`.

Comment: java_CA1.java:107: error: reached end of file while parsing

there is the exact error, sorry I thought i had it added

Comment: Not sure how that comment relates to my answer.  Are you saying that you get that AFTER you fix up the `else` lines?

Comment: I apologise I am new to this website I meant to add it to the general comments

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `for` loop and an `array` to hold the answers. You really don't need the array at all for this problem, but in case you want values  you can match with your `ans`.

```
char[] array = new char[12];

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    System.out.println("1) Do You like Computers?");

     array[i] = Keyboard.readChar();

     while (array[i] != 'y' && array[i] != 'n'
         && array[i] != 'Y' && array[i] != 'N'){

         System.out.println("That is an invalid selection," + 
                            "please enter y or n to answer the questions");

         array[i] = Keyboard.readChar();
     }

     if(array[i] == 'y' || array[i] == 'Y'){
         totaly++;
     }
     else {
         totaln++;
     }

}
```